# Symbol for "anything"

Tags: pattern-matching

Is there a way to use in Mathematica something like "anything" symbol to simplify symbolic expressions?

Exemplary, I would like to denote with "B[*]" B[t] for arbitrary parameter t. In particular, I could then simplify expression (where B[t], A are some matrices):

```
(B[t1].B[t2].A +A.B[t3].B[t4]+B[t4].A.B[t5])/.{B[*].B[*]->IdentityMatrix},
```

where IdentityMatrix is self-explanatory, to get an output 2A+B[t4].A.B[t5].

Comment: The pattern for "Anything" is "_" not "*"

Comment: Oh, great, I was not aware of it and was not able to find it by google. If you make it an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern for "Anything" is "_" not "*". E.g.:

```
(B[t1] . B[t2] . A + A . B[t3] . B[t4] + 
   B[t4] . A . B[t5]) /. {B[_] . B[_] -> IdentityMatrix}

(* A . IdentityMatrix + IdentityMatrix . A + B[t4] . A . B[t5] *)
```